# Probability: arithmetic on Random Variables

Tags: probability, random-variables

I have a question about the arithmetic on random variable in probability.

[image]

Question: Are the events $\{X=Y\}$, $\{Y=Z\}$,$\{Z=X\}$ independent?

My solution:

$$
  P(X=Y,Y=Z,Z=X)
= {(0.5^2 +0.5^2)}*{(0.5^2 +0.5^2)}*{(0.5^2 +0.5^2)}
=  0.5^3 =1/4
$$

But

$$
  P(X=Y,Y=Z,Z=X)=P(X=Y=Z)
= 0.5^3+0.5^3=1/8
$$
This doesn't make any sense!

Comment: How did you get 
$$
  0.5^2 + 0.5^2 + 0.5^2 + 0.5^2 + 0.5^2 + 0.5^2 
= 3 \cdot 0.5^2?
$$

Comment: my bad, I will change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First compute 
\begin{align}
   P[X=Y]
&= P[X=0,Y=0] + P[X=1,Y=1] \\
&= P[X=0]P[Y=0] + P[X=1]P[Y=1] \\
&= \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) + 
   \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{2},
\end{align}
and similarly
$$
  P[Y=Z]
= \frac{1}{2},
$$
then compute
\begin{align}
   P[X=Y, Y=Z]
&= P[X=Y=Z] \\
&= P[X=0,Y=0,Z=0] + P[X=1,Y=1,Z=1] \\
&= P[X=0]P[Y=0]P[Z=0] + P[X=1]P[Y=1]P[Z=1] \\
&= \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) + 
   \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{4}.
\end{align}
So the events $\{ X=Y\}$ and $\{Y=Z\}$ are independent. By symmetry you could have considered the sets $\{ X=Y\}$ and $\{Z=X\}$ and shown that these are independent as well.

Comment: please see my update

Comment: Here you show pair-wise independent only.

Comment: I assumed that is what the question is asking. You can infer from this that they are not mutually independent though: I've computed already 
$$
  P[X=Y,Y=Z,Z=X]
= P[X=Y=Z]
= \frac{1}{4}
$$
as well as the probability of the individual terms from which you get
$$
  P[X=Y]P[Y=Z]P[Z=X]
= \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)
= \frac{1}{8}.
$$

Comment: for the first equation in your comment, P(X=Y,Y=Z,Z=X)=P(X=Y=Z), this is logic comes from?

Comment: It comes from the fact that 
$$
  \{X=Y,Y=Z,Z=X\}
= \{X=Y=Z\}.
$$

Comment: Ok, if you have something like {X=Y, Y=Z}, do you still have {X=Y,Y=Z}={X=Y=Z}?

Comment: Just think about it. If $x=y$ and $y=z$, is it true that $x=y=z$?

Comment: Yes, it is, so in that sense, you can think it in terms of variables? (ordinary math variable)

Comment: The set $\{ X=Y, Y=Z\}$ is a set of points $\omega \in \Omega$ satisfying $X(\omega)=Y(\omega)$ and $Y(\omega)=Z(\omega)$. When you apply the random variables to $\omega$ you  get fixed numbers, so you can treat them as such. (Here $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ is the probability space you are working on).